# wild-card search in postgres

Tags: postgresql, search, wildcard

Is there a way for me to search using wild-card `%` in Postgres to only retain the searches that have non-zero replacement of `%`? So `%a%` should only result in `cab` but not `a`.
If not with `%`, is there another simple way to do so?
Thanks!

Comment: Use `_` instead of `%`.

Answer (score 2):

From the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html)

> An underscore (_) in pattern stands for (matches) any single
>   character; a percent sign (%) matches any sequence of zero or more
>   characters.

You need to use `_` instead of `%`

**Edited**
Final expression as suggested by [@Abelisto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/593144/abelisto) should be `'%_a_%'`

Comment: I think "non-zero" (one or more) means `%_a_%`